# Take snapshots in GCP using script

Tags: google-compute-engine

I need to take a snaphots of all my servers from script in all projects in GCP.

Project count : 10

Servers per project : 05

Written the script in a Server: Automation-server

Script has:

`gcloud compute  --project $PROJECT_ID  disks snapshot ${DEVICE_NAME} --snapshot-names gcp-${DEVICE_NAME}-${DATE} --zone ${INSTANCE_ZONE})`

As of now i have **configured my E-mail** id in the Server X
with `gcloud auth`
(My E-mail id has access to all of my projects so that i can able to take snapshots of all the servers)
So i can able to do the same via scripting.

I wish not to do this via a **user authentication**(mentioning the E-mail id) .

Is there any possiblity for doing the above via any application or using any api-key etc..,
By granting the access of all the projects to a application or api-key and by using that , taking the snapshots from the script

This will be used in :

If a user X has access to 5 projects , and an user  Y has access to another set of 5 projects.

Need to take snapshots for all the 10 projects using script
at this time if the `gcloud auth` was done via an application or api-key etc..,

Is it possible or any other way for the above case

Answer (score 1):

This is possible:

1. Create a [service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts) in cloud project.
2. Go to each of your 10 projects, and grant the service account either "Editor", "compute.instanceAdmin" or "compute.storageAdmin" IAM permission.
3. Use `gcloud auth activate-service-account` in your script to have the script run as the service account.

You could also use multiple service accounts for different projects, and switch between the.

Comment: While i m creating the service account in one of my project , it reports as `You don't have permission to modify project permissions. To give the service account access to this project, ask a project owner to add it to the project permissions.` . Currently  i m having the `editor`  , `service account admin ` access. other than this what are all the access needs to be get from `owner` for creating/editing the service account

Comment: As the error message says, you need to be a project owner to create a service account.

This flowchart can help you figure out how to use a service account
https://cloud.google.com/iam/img/sa-flowchart.png

This script from GitHub can help you with the snapshots, it's always a good idea to remove old snapshots so you won't get out of space:
https://gist.github.com/peihsinsu/73cb7e28780b137c2bcd